# Form submission and recaptcha not working on submit

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I am trying to implement a reCAPTCHA on my html form, and I followed the steps outlined in Google documentation but the button isn't working now when you click 'Submit".
The reCAPTCHA doesn't show either.

The form itself is handled by PHP, not sure if that has anything to do with it, but figured it was worth mentioning. I took out the site key and replaced it with the word "hidden" :).

Code is below.

```
         <script>
           function onSubmit(token) {
             document.getElementById("demo-form").submit();
           }
         </script>
                    
          <form action="index.php"
           method="post"
           name="EmailForm">
            <div class="col-8">
              <div class="input-text">
                <div class="input-headers">
                 
                      <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                      <br>
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Full name" required="required">
             
                      <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                      <br>
                      <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Email address" required="required">
             
                      <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                      <br>
                      <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Enter a subject" required="required">
           
                      <label for="message">Message</label>
                      <br>
                      <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="message" 
rows="4" placeholder="Your message" required="required"></textarea>

                  <br>

                  <button type="submit" 
                  value="submit"
                  class="btn btn-primary g-recaptcha"
                  data-sitekey="hidden"
                  data-callback="onSubmit"
                  data-action="Submit">Submit</button>

                  <br>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>

 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your form should have the `id="demo-form"`

Comment: This seemed to work, thanks!